# Django Admin Not Showing Correct Timezone Value Returned by Custom Method

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-admin

I have a table field in my models that is a storing tz aware datetime's as UTC, along with a method to present the datetime in another tz, like so --

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
import pytz

class Game(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow,
                                      blank=True,null=True)

    def start_time_as_et(self):
        '''returns start_time as ET, not as UTC'''
        eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
        return self.start_time.astimezone(eastern)
```

My admin.py has --

```
from django.contrib import admin
from g.models import Game

class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('start_time_as_et',)
```

I thought that should display the ET version of the datetime in the admin interface, but I'm still getting the UTC showing in the admin interface. I tried removing the default from the start_time value but that didn't change anything. I'm not sure if I'm missing something about how this works or if this only works for True/False values (as in the Django tutorial). And yes, the TZ setting is set in the settings.py, so that's not a problem. I did some Googling but couldn't find out if anyone's had a problem like this before or how I can fix it.

I'm using Django 1.11.x, Python 3.5.2, on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I'm guessing that the admin normalizes dates to your timezone. Try returning a string from `start_time_as_et` instead of a datetime object